# Scroll DIV Horizontally with Mouse Events

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a layout as follows:

```
<div style="width: 300">
    <div style="width: 300">Some Content</div>
</div
```

I want to be able to mousedown in the content DIV and be able to move it left to right, or scroll it in other words :)

What would be the best way of being this?

I would prefer it in JavaScript mainly :)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand... you want to be able to click and Drag the content DIV left and right, or you want to scroll it? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Want to be able to scroll it, changing the ScrollLeft value for the parent div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to use Mootools or jQuery. Both have "drag" interfaces to handle this sort of thing, and handle all the cross-browser compatibility problems.

If you're fixed on rolling your own, then the basic process is to attach mousedown/mouseup events on the parent div to initiate the dragging stuff, slap a handler on mousemove to capture the motion events, and adjust the parent div's scroll offsets as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Better add css to your div

```
div id {
width:300px;
height:300px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

and write the JQuery or javascript you want to do.